# Looking for the log file on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file

I have a problem.
I have the code below for save a data on file.
I build my app on the device, and run.
The result variable is TRUE, but i don't find the file on the my iPhone device.
Can you help me?
Thank and sorry for my english XP

```
 -(void)saveXML:(NSString*)name:(float)x:(float)y:(float)z{

    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver setOutputFormat:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0];
    [archiver encodeFloat:x forKey:@"x"];
    [archiver encodeFloat:y forKey:@"y"];
    [archiver encodeFloat:z forKey:@"z"];
    [archiver encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    NSString* filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XML Position"];
    BOOL result = [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    if(result)
        [self   updateTextView:@"success"];
    [archiver release];

 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with saveToFile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934368/problem-with-savetofile)

Answer (score 0):

On the device, the corresponding code:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XML Position"];
```

gives the following value to `filePath`:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/<<UUID>>/Documents/XML Position
```

where `UUID` is the unique application identifier.

Comment: NSString* filePath = @"/var/mobile/Applications/<<myApplicationIdentifier>>/Documents/XML Position"; but isn't correct

Comment: @zp26: Don't try and use an absolute path. Use the same methods in the question (i.e., NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomain) to construct the path back to the file.